# Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeingiter platform to build an application. I am facing an error while trying to use unset() function in a controller. I have an array which looks like:

> Array ( [userfile] => Screenshot from 2014-11-02 21:36:32.png 
>   [pause_flag] => 0 [merchant_top] => 0 [category_id] => 1
>   [category_id1] => 1 [category_id2] => 1 )

While trying to unset 'userfile' from the array using **unset($this->input->post('userfile'));**
I am getting an error which suggests  **Can't use method return value in write context.**

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: the error already speaks clearly, you cant unset the value thru `->post()` method. and why do you need to unset it anyway?

Comment: What you're trying to doesn't really make sense. It would be useless to unset post(), as once it is being processed, the request has already been submitted and cannot be altered from the client side.

Comment: @wold.. The controller is on the server side and I am trying to alter the data on the server side. $this->input->post() is just an array .. so is it not possible to manipulate the array using unset() function ?

Comment: You can, you would have to use erv-Z's method and assign post() to a variable and unset it on the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[unset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) is used for unset the content of a variable or array, but you are passing a method return insted a variable or array.